ParameterType inaccessible error when upgrading from 2020 to 2023
I'm working on upgrading a project from Revit 2020 to Revit 2023, and I'm encountering this error:
"'ParameterType' is inaccessible due to its protection level"
This occurs in my code where I'm working with parameter types.
After some research, it seems this issue is related to API changes between these versions where ParameterType is being replaced.
Could someone confirm if I need to update my code to use SpecTypeId instead of ParameterType? And if so, what would be the correct syntax to migrate from Revit 2020 to 2023?
Thanks in advance!
P.S. I'm upgrading from Revit 2020 to Revit 2023 API.

Have you checked the docs? They show this type was deprecated in 2022 and removed in 2023. The deprecation message in 2022 according to the docs was This property is deprecated in Revit 2022 and may be removed in a future version of Revit. Please use the GetDataType() method instead.

Thanks for your answer. Yes I tried but it doesn't work and I have even more errors. I also tried to replace parameterType with ForgeTypeId but it led to another error.

What did you try and what were those errors? We can't help without any information. Right now all the question says is that it tried to use a non-existent type. Just as I found the docs simply by googling for Revit ParameterType or the error message, you'll be able to find docs or solutions for whatever type you're trying to use or error message
